# Busqueda en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, busqueda

Buen día.

Tengo una duda, como puedo hacer para que en MYSQL una busqueda no sea sensible a acentos,mayusculas y minusculas?, esto usando LIKE.

En mi base de datos tengo "Héctor García", cuando busque "hector" me de ese registro:

Actualmente uso:  `select * from tutabla where nombre like '%hector%'`

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes forzar una "busqueda insensible" para la tabla de esta forma:

```
select * from tutabla where nombre like '%hector%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_Al
```

Así mismo, tu Query estaría sin la sensibilidad del tilde.

Answer (score 0):

En la  BD, el campo de la tabla donde se va a buscar debe tener utf8_spanish_ci en COLLATION, y si el campo es tipo BLOB debe de usarse la función CONVERT.